# Page path value - JS variable

Tags: javascript

I have to return site type (business or personal) value from page path

The function I use is:

```js
    function currentPath() {
      var siteType=window.location.pathname;
      if ( siteType.indexOf('business')) {
        siteType= 'business';
      } else {
        siteType = 'personal';
      }
      return siteType;
    }
```

So if page path contains "business", it should return business and if it does not contain "business" it should return "personal".

Comment: I assume you forgot to check indexOf correctly: `siteType.indexOf('business')!==-1` Or simple use `includes`

Answer (score 1):

Use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
function currentPath() {
  var siteType = window.location.pathname;
  if (siteType.includes('business')) {
    return 'business';
  } else {
    return 'personal';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof)

```
function currentPath() {
  var siteType=window.location.pathname;
  if ( siteType.indexOf('business') !== -1) { //return -1 if not present
    siteType= 'business';
  } else {
    siteType = 'personal';
  }
  return siteType;
}
```

or

[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
function currentPath() {
  var siteType=window.location.pathname;
  if (siteType.includes('business')) { //checks for the string in the given string or array
    siteType= 'business';
  } else {
    siteType = 'personal';
  }
  return siteType;
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the `else`. You can `return 'business'` if the condition matches or `return 'personal'`.

Comment: can be done in both ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includes()` method with conditional operator:

```js
function currentPath() {
  return window.location.pathname.includes('business') ? 'business' : 'personal';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `indexOf` in a if/else condition you need to check the index so you can proceed `if (siteType.indexOf('business') > -1)...` for example.

Modern JS allows us to use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), and a little [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
function currentPath() {
  const { pathname } = window.location;
  if (pathname.includes('business')) return 'business';
  return 'personal';
}
```